# Why can't I deep copping a DICT out of a function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dictionary, deep-copy

I'm using [request](https://github.com/request/request) to call an API which gives me movies data in an object called body, but when I try to pass it to an array and console log it, the terminal shows me an empty array.

```
let copy = [];

const request = require('request');

request('https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=JOKER&apikey=b04f2804', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err);}
  copy.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)))
});

console.log(copy);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `request()` library is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) and it is not recommended that you write new code with it.  There is a list of alternatives (that all support promises) [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

Then second, the `request()` library is non-blocking and asynchronous.  That means that when you call `request()`, it starts the operation and then immediately returns.  The code after the call to `request()` then continues to execute BEFORE `request()` calls its callback.  So, you're trying to examine the array before its value has been set.  This is a classic issue in asynchronous programming.  There are a number of ways to handle this.  If you stayed with the `request()` library, then you must either use the result INSIDE the callback itself or you can call some other function from within that callback and pass it the array.

With one of the listed alternatives that all support promises (my favorite is the `got()` library), you can then use `await` which is often a preferred programming style for asynchronous operations:

```
const got = require('got');

async function someFunction() {
    let result = await got('https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=JOKER&apikey=b04f2804').json();
    // you can use the result here
    console.log(result);

    // Or you can return it and it will become the resolved value
    // of the promise this async function returns
    return result;
}

someFunction().then(result => {
    // can use result here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note that when you are writing asynchronously retrieved data to a higher scoped variable as you are when you do `copy.push()`, that is typically a warning that you're doing something wrong.  This is because NONE of the code in the higher scope will know when the data is available in that variable.  There are rare cases when you might do that (like for implementing a cache), but these have to be situations where the data is being stored only for future reference, not for immediate use.  99.9% of the time when we see that construct, it's a wrong way to program with asynchronously retrieved data.